# PHP Description in html tables

Tags: php, html

so I'm writing this real estate website and i have a page for each property with a name, picture, description, etc. 
It is all inside a table with a couple of rows.
My problem is with the description. It takes a description from my SQL database and posts it into the table but it looks weird.

http://puu.sh/hEX6a/cb3b9f9b71.jpg

as you see in this image it goes off the page and table. But with the same settings and another page from a page i added earlier

http://puu.sh/hEXhk/f3ed4143f8.jpg

text looks perfectly fine. 
What may be the problem ?

```
 <table  width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="15"  cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
 <td valign="top" width="19%"><img src="images/<?php echo $id; ?>/pic1.jpg" 
 width="210" height="152" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" /></td>
 <td valign="top" width="81%" ><h3>Име: <?php echo $product_name; ?></h3>
 <p>Price: <?php echo $price ;  ?> лв.<br />
 <p>Hood: <?php echo $kvartal; ?> </p>  
 <p>Тype: <?php echo $tip; ?> </p>  
 <p>buy/sell: <?php echo $kakvo; ?> </p> 
 Описание:   <?php  echo $details ; ?></p>
</table>
```

Comment: Set a maximum width for the table via css.

Comment: table width="300px" for example, set it fixed

Comment: how do i set properties for a table in css?

Comment: have u close your <td> tag?

Comment: I tried changing up some things and I ended up with this http://puu.sh/hEYz3/8c8da14d23.jpg 
is there any way to break the lines without using <br>

Comment: dont use work without space to test does something work u use string with to many characters it is single word

Comment: Okay, using actual text to test seems to work about alright. That is werid. Thank you Adnan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, you are missing a few opening and closing of HTML tags.
I have added them and formatted a little your code.

```
<table  width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="15"  cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="19%">
      <img src="images/<?php echo $id; ?>/pic1.jpg" width="210" height="152" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="81%" >
      <h3>Име: <?php echo $product_name; ?></h3>
      <p>Price: <?php echo $price ;  ?> лв.</p>
      <p>Hood: <?php echo $kvartal; ?> </p>  
      <p>Тype: <?php echo $tip; ?> </p>  
      <p>buy/sell: <?php echo $kakvo; ?> </p> 
      <p>Описание:   <?php  echo $details ; ?></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, your problem seems to be related to string with words longer than the size of your column. By default, words are kept complete so they look weird in your layout.

To solve this, you need to set the [word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) property of your `p` elements to `break-word`, you can do this adding a rule to your style-sheet.

p { word-wrap: break-word; }

Or if you are not using style-sheets (shame on you), add this rule inside a scoped `style` tag like this:

```
<div>
  <style type="text/css" scoped>
     p { word-wrap: break-word; }
  </style>

  <table  width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="15"  cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="19%">
        <img src="images/<?php echo $id; ?>/pic1.jpg" width="210" height="152" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" />
      </td>
      <td valign="top" width="81%" >
        <h3>Име: <?php echo $product_name; ?></h3>
        <p>Price: <?php echo $price ;  ?> лв.</p>
        <p>Hood: <?php echo $kvartal; ?> </p>  
        <p>Тype: <?php echo $tip; ?> </p>  
        <p>buy/sell: <?php echo $kakvo; ?> </p> 
        <p>Описание:   <?php  echo $details ; ?></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am really new to making websites in general. I didn't really know about strings not braking down words(Now that i think about it, it kind of makes sense). And I am using a stylesheet.